# Color Picker for Metro Style app?

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-metro

I am trying to add ColorPicker to my metro style app. 
After making a little research, I have found that Extended WPF Toolkit contains ColorPicker. 
But when I try to add the .dll file to my project via "Add Reference" it says:

*"The project targets .NETCore while the file reference targets .NETFramework. This is not a supported scenario."*

My question is, How to add this .dll file? Is it possible to compile this .dll so that is targets .NETCore? 
And 
Is there any other(simple) way to implement a Color Picker in Metro Style App?

(I am completely new with the concepts of WPF. Please correct me if I made any mistake. )

Comment: You might ask in their discussions area (http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/discussions) if they plan on releasing a version that targets .NETCore. I think it unlikely that the entire library will compile straight-away, but you might also ask about using only a portion of it (the color picker) and build just that into a .NETCore targeted assembly.

Comment: You'll need to keep the user interface requirements in mind.  Pretty hard to pick a color from a standard color picker dialog with a fat finger.  A touch user interface requires something very different.  Think tiles.

Comment: This solution may work for you. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/1cb9c5b9-3ef6-4c88-b747-ae222c38c922/

Answer (score 1):

It's not from Microsoft, and ColorPicker is not yet done (it's described as "in development"), but you can certainly try it.  http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have recently tested it it works Good in metro apps as well . if your is not working well try to add wpf extended file through Nuget Packages it will work fine :)